# Double Click vba with event on first click and second click

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro, activated by a button, that deletes the row(s) highlighted by the cursor. I want to update the macro to incorporate double click functionality wherein on the first click those rows being deleted will be highlighted (effectively a warning) and on the double click they will actually be deleted (current macro will run). If the double click does not follow within the stipulated double click speed i.e. only one click, I want the row's formatting to revert. Say this window for the second click is 2 seconds. Can anyone help? My current macro is below. I would like this to run on double click. Thank you!

```
Sub DELETE_ROW_MASTER()
Application.EnableEvents = False
Select Case ActiveSheet.Name
Case "ESTIMATE SHEET"
    Dim rng As Range
        Set rng = Selection.EntireRow
            ' Alert telling you no deleting those rows if row is higher than specific row or if selection includes title row
            If rng.Row <= 31 Or Range("d" & (rng.Row)).Value = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Can't Delete That Row")
            End If
                   
            'Stipulate only rows below specified can be deleted
            If rng.Row > 31 And Range("d" & (rng.Row)).Value <> 0 Then
            ' Delete the current row
            rng.EntireRow.Delete
            End If
Case Else
    MsgBox ("Macro not for this sheet.")
End Select
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You will require the worksheet events, selection_change and before_doubleClick events. Look both up,

Comment: Sadly, I haven't quite got there with either of these. Simplifying the ask, I need a ribbon button to highlight active row on one click for 2 seconds. If second click in 2 seconds occurs, delete activerow. If no second click occurs in 2 seconds, revert formatting. Is this temporary formatting possible?

Comment: Check out worksheet change events first,  -[simple worksheet event sample](https://www.excelforum.com/tips-and-tutorials/1078377-automate-worksheet-with-worksheet-events.html)